# ASP button reloading page?

Tags: asp.net

I have this code on an aspx page:

```
<div id="bloc1">
    Hey you
</div>

<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button2_Click" OnClientClick="change_page()" />
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="change_page()" />

<div id="bloc2" style="display:none">
    Hey me
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function change_page() {
        document.getElementById("bloc2").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("bloc1").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

When I click on the HTML button, my script works well: Bloc1 disappears and Bloc2 appears.

When I click on the ASP button, Bloc1 disappears and Bloc2 appears very quickly and Bloc2 disappears and Bloc1 re-appears (so back to the beginning) as if the page was reloaded.

Behind code does something:

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Button2.Text = "new Button";
    }
```

How can I manage to do like the HTML button, but with the behind code function?

PS: I don't want to use UpdatePanel and ScriptManager.

Comment: It is because asp:button is a server control when u click page gets post back so its gets refreshed.

Comment: Yes you're right. So how can I manage to use server function but still be able to use javascript function like in html?

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand the difference between ASP.NET WebForms and how the HTML web page actually works. The `<asp:Button>` control renders markup as `<input type="submit">`, regardless of whether or not you have a `OnClick` event tied to it. This means that your form will be submitted to the server upon click, unless you stop it with javascript.

Your server doesn't know what you've done in javascript with showing and hiding things, since things like CSS `display` aren't part of the post. So when the page loads again, it's back to the way it was the first time it was loaded.

You can't have it both ways - either you post to the server and get a new page, or you don't. If you need to execute server code without a full post and full load, then you'll need to do some AJAX - that can happen with either UpdatePanels, or with proper AJAX (for example, jQuery with an ASHX handler or a `WebMethod` method).

Comment: Ok thank you for the explaination!
I'll check Ajax then. I don't want to use updatepanels for some reason

Comment: I don't blame you for not wanting to use UpdatePanels. They're an interesting idea, but in reality they're horrible things. They use hundreds of times more bandwidth than proper AJAX, run entire page lifecycles unnecessarily, and are just a pain to work with. The only advantage is that if you're already heavily WebForms-centric, it's relatively easy to switch from full posts to partial posts without a lot of changes. But if you build your site properly from the start, understanding the difference between server and client code, proper AJAX will actually be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your ASP:Button is a control which is run at server i.e. it submits button and then reloads the page its original state.

You have two options:

1) If you just need this to be client side function then don't use ASP:Button and just use the input button you setup and the change_page() to change view.

2) If you want to submit back to server and run code behind to do some other server side scripting then remove change_page() script from asp:Button and show hide divs in codebehind.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // other server side scripts...

    bloc1.Visible = false;
    bloc2.Visible = true;

}
```

Comment: Ok so i should add runat="server" on both div?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you go to server side on clicking on the button. You have two solutions:

1. Remove this from the ASP button onclick="Button2_Click":

   ```
   <div id="bloc1">
       Hey you
   </div>

   <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button2_Click" OnClientClick="change_page()" />
   <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="change_page()" />

   <div id="bloc2" style="display:none">
       Hey me
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       function change_page() {
           document.getElementById("bloc2").style.display = "block";
           document.getElementById("bloc1").style.display = "none";
       }
   </script>
   ```
2. Keep it, but add return false; after calling JavaScript function like this:

   ```
   <div id="bloc1">
       Hey you
   </div>

   <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button2_Click"
               OnClientClick="change_page();return false;" />
   <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="change_page()" />

   <div id="bloc2" style="display:none">
       Hey me
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       function change_page() {
           document.getElementById("bloc2").style.display = "block";
           document.getElementById("bloc1").style.display = "none";
       }
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make the `asp` button tag like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="YourID" UseSubmitBehavior="false" cssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Take a Snap" OnClientClick="take_snapshot();" /> or
<asp:Button ID="YourID" cssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Take a Snap" OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

Actually, you can change the attribute UseSubmitBehavier or in OnClientClick method simply return false in the method you call in onClientClick. And when you want the page to be reloaded you can return true then.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change_page() {
        document.getElementById("bloc2").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("bloc1").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button2_Click" OnClientClick="return change_page();" />

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Your code
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType,"Test", "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>change_page();</script>");
}
```

Comment: Yes it works. But what if I want to something in behind code?
Like: this.Button2.Text = "lol"
It doesn't work anymore